# Python beginner- Is there any problems just using multiple functions for a program?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python so sorry if this is a weird question.
For a class assignment we had to produce a program.
The way my program is organised is just a series of functions then a section to call the functions. Is there anything wrong with structuring it like this rather than just putting the functions in the main code. 
For example:

```
def a():
    do a list of things

def b():
    do b list of things

a(argumenta)    
b(argumentb)
```

rather than

```
do a list of things
do b list of things
```

I find it easier to test sections of my code at a time in functions. Would I need to restructure all of my code or would it be fine. My code is currently 220 lines long just for some scope. Sorry for poor formatting and thank you in advance.

Comment: In most situations this is a good idea, in fact.

Comment: Googeling _Clean code_ or  _SOLID principles_ etc will give you plenty of reasons and opinions about that.

Comment: FWIW, overdoing it is called "the wrong abstraction", but you're probably not writing complex enough programs yet for that to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

It could be fine, if you don't want to use recursion.
I think using recursion will help you to gain more marks.

```
def a():
    do a list of things

    if true_condition:
        a(argumenta)
    elif condition:
        b(argumentb)
    else:
        return

def b():
    do b list of things
    if true_condition:
        b(argumentb)
    elif condition:
        a(argumenta)
    else:
        return
```

Structure of using recursion up to you and your requirements

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No. Not only there is no problem with using functions, but it is also very good.

**More explained**: A code with multiple functions is better than an unstructured code.
Unstructured code is hard to test, maintain and read and for understanding what is doing each part of code, you have to read a lot of codes. But for example if you have structured your codes into functions, you simply can understand each part by seeing function names. By using functions your code will be more readable, testable and maintainable and also with doing that you can reduce duplicate codes.

For example in your sample code you can call a() and b() functions anytime you want and many times (like in loops or in recursion functions).

Based on your programming paradigm you can structure your code in more abstract structures like classes and also use functions inside of classes (methods).